# Why Posting Form values in HTTP-Headers

Tags: forms, rest, http-headers, oracle-apex

yesterday i had to check some code from an Oracle APEX REST Web Service, and i found that the developer asked to post values via HTTP Headers.

```
POST http://IP#.IP#.IP#.IP#/api/direction/users/cre/ HTTP/1.1
Host: IP#.IP#.IP#.IP#
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0
Accept: All
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://webSite.com/createAccount/validateUser.html
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
value_a: this is a form Value
value_b: this is another form value
value_c: this is another form value
value_card_d: this is a sensitive form value
Origin: http://webSite.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

What i don't understand is why would anyone put form values inside post headers, what is the benefit of doing this, is it more secure under a HTTPS connection?

Instead of putting:

```
value_a: this is a form Value
value_b: this is another form value
value_c: this is another form value
value_card_d: this is a sensitive form value
```

Inside of the request body?
Note: It is a POST request, not a HEAD request.